# Name for mconcat implementation for applicative monoid

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have implemented a function `mcollect` which is effectively `mconcat` only for applicative monoids:

```
mcollect
  :: Applicative f
  => Monoid (f a)
  => [a]
  -> f a
mcollect = mconcat . fmap pure
```

However I am not overly keen on the name `mcollect`, an alternative name in the spirit of `mconcat` is `amconcat` which I am not keen on either. Looking on Hoogle there does not appear to be anything like this in any libraries, that I can find. Does something like this exist somewhere already, I've just missed it? Is there a better name for this function?

Comment: could you clarify why lifting applicative monoids into `Ap`  as already supported by `mconcat` is not sufficient for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't give this a name. It is equal to `foldMap pure` and feels to me like it might be refactored away with more context.